Python - Django - MySQL #need to add distinct() after select_related().distinct() in views.py
so this is ads/views.py
there's a ads/models.py, ads/forms, ads/urls.py and other files, but the one that the grader is complaining is this views.py...
3806 characters of HTML retrieved
Test completed: Found menu bar at the top of the page
Found more than one ad when searching for 'HHGTTG_42 1717639962'.
You probably need to add distinct() after select_related().distinct() ... in your views.py
so i tried using the select_related().distinct() and adding it after, but is not working :(
views.py Section that's causing issues:
class AdListView(ListView):
    model = Ad  # Specify the model you're working with
    template_name = "ads/ad_list.html"

    def get(self, request):
        strval = request.GET.get("search", False)
        if strval:
            query = Q(title__icontains=strval) | Q(text__icontains=strval) | Q(tags__name__in=[strval])
            #query.add(Q(text__icontains=strval), Q.OR)
            #query.add(Q(tags__name__in=[strval]), Q.OR)

            ad_list = Ad.objects.filter(query).order_by('-updated_at').distinct()
        else:
            ad_list = Ad.objects.all().order_by('-updated_at')

        # Apply distinct() explicitly
        # ad_list = ad_list.distinct()

        for obj in ad_list:
            obj.natural_updated = naturaltime(obj.updated_at)

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            favorites = list(request.user.favorite_ads.values_list('id', flat=True))
        else:
            favorites = []

        ctx = {'ad_list': ad_list, 'favorites': favorites, 'search': strval}
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

models.py
    from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "Title must be greater than 2 characters")]
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tagme_owner')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    picture = models.BinaryField(null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True, help_text='The MIMEType of the file')
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Comment', related_name='tagme_comments')
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Fav', related_name='favorite_ads')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(3, "Comment must be greater than 3 characters")]
    )
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:20] + ("..." if len(self.text) > 20 else "")

class Fav(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " likes " + self.ad.title

forms.py
    from django import forms
from ads.models import Ad, Comment
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from ads.humanize import naturalsize
from taggit.forms import TagWidget

class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    max_upload_limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024
    max_upload_limit_text = naturalsize(max_upload_limit)

    picture = forms.FileField(required=False, label='File to Upload <= '+max_upload_limit_text)
    upload_field_name = 'picture'

    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = ['title', 'price', 'text', 'tags', 'picture']
        widgets = {
            'tags': TagWidget(),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        pic = cleaned_data.get('picture')
        if pic and isinstance(pic, InMemoryUploadedFile):
            if pic.size > self.max_upload_limit:
                self.add_error('picture', "File must be < " + self.max_upload_limit_text + " bytes")
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(CreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        f = instance.picture
        if isinstance(f, InMemoryUploadedFile):
            bytearr = f.read()
            instance.content_type = f.content_type
            instance.picture = bytearr
        if commit:
            instance.save()
            self.save_m2m()  # Save many-to-many fields like tags
        return instance

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']


distinct will only eliminate duplicates, it does not guarantee that you will only get one model instance. What is your actual requirement? Which Ad should be chosen when there is no search keyword? Also post the Ad model.

done, I've added models.py and forms.py; both are important... It's a project, and it goes through an autograder... i didn't know the requirement was to have a distinct() in there... it's just telling me after I run their autograder for checking my code
